# Fromname in mail using sendgrid mail api

Tags: sendgrid

I'm trying to send emails using sendgrid mail API.
Everything works fine. However, I want my emails to have a specific name.
Not the prefix of the sender's address, which is coming up by default.

I changed the `From` value to "`MY_email_name <sender@example.com>`". But it didn't work.

I have set the `From_Name` field to "`MY_email_name`". That too didn't work.

However, it's working when I not read the html content from an external file and instead give some inline. In that case it is sending me the email_name.
Any idea about how I can do this with reading the content.

Thanks.

```
var sendgrid  = require('sendgrid')('MY_APP_SECRET');
var fs  = require('fs');

var content;
// First I want to read the file
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/email.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;

    // Invoke the next step here however you like
    //console.log(content);   // Put all of the code here (not the best solution)
    processFile();          // Or put the next step in a function and invoke it
});

function processFile() {
    console.log(content);
}



module.exports =  function sendMail(mailObject){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){



    // create a new email instance
    var email = new sendgrid.Email();

    email.addTo('some1@example.com');
    email.setFrom('sender@example.com');
    email.setSubject('My-Email-body');
    email.setFromName("Email-Name");
    email.setHtml(content);
    email.addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API');
    email.addHeader('X-Transport', 'web');

    email.setASMGroupID(835);
    //send mail
    sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
        //if something went wrong
        if (err) { reject({
            error:err,
            res : json,
        }); }

        //else
        resolve({
              statusText: 'OK',
              res : json
        });
      });
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try From('sender@example.com') and FromName('first last <sender@example.com>')